# SQL Server - Alter column length causes collateral damage?

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table, alter-column

Besides the obvious possible data loss, when altering the size from `varchar(MAX)` to `varchar(255)`, are there any side effects? Like:

- table-lock?
- index corruption?
- Automatic re-indexing?

This is the kind of activity that can be conducted at any time of day or it should be confined to a "maintenance window"?

Comment: The action itself is pretty harmless. I can't imagine it taking a long time to make a field smaller like that. So it could be doable at any time.

Comment: It depends. You can specify ONLINE = ON depending on your SQL Server version which changes the behavior and also want to make sure you are not going from NULL to NOT NULL for example. Some paths lead to size-of data operations which mean heavy log activity, blocking, etc. I am fairly certain SQL Server will have to validate that no data > new size. In some cases it might be more efficient to create a new column, copy the data over in batches, drop the old column, rename the new. This is disruptive of course.

Comment: What did you observe when you tested this in your developement environment?

Comment: There is no obvious possible data loss. The entire operation will fail in the case of truncation. Index corruption will occur only due to hardware issue or SQL bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In changing the varchar(max) column to varchar(n) or vice versa, SQL Server will update all rows of the table. This can temporarily increase the size of the table until rebuild cluster index or execute `DBCC CLEANTABLE`.